# Cannot load module 'Arkit' as 'ARKit'

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit

[image]

Arkit module is not loading even added in linked frameworks and libraries.

Comment: Are you on Xcode 11 beta?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth: Are you from the future? – You perhaps mean Xcode 9 beta, or iOS 11.

Comment: Oops, right, ha. Probably because I read the `11` in the tags while typing… @MartinR

Comment: xcode 9 beta 4.

Comment: Have you done the standard procedures aka "Have you tried turning it on and off again?" Cleaned the project, restarted Xcode, maybe even rebooted your Mac?

Comment: Almost edited this question but, well, not sure. To the OP - everywhere - in Xcode, your code, your question title, even your question - it's **ARKit**, not **Arkit**. So.... WHY is your question text (the last sentence) stating that "Arkit module is not loading"? Please, fix this - be it either in your question (which spoke of Xcode 11) or hopefully in your code someplace!

Comment: @dfd have you read the post?! The error message clearly states `Arkit` being lowercased. Perhaps OP typed `Arkit`, the error message appeared and OP changed it to `ARKit`.

Answer (score 8):

Just rename your module, it's conflict with framework name :)

[image]

Comment: OP even said it in the post…

Answer (score 1):

Never call your project using the same name as the framework has (like ARKit, Vision, or RealityKit). It doesn't matter what character you're using uppercased or lowercased. It causes a serious conflict and your project won't start in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is unable to distinguish between your project name **'Arkit'** and apple framework **'ARKit'**.

> Project name is not case sensitive.

Better create a project with a different name.